# EtherumJ EthereumFactory.createEthereum() taking long hours

Tags: ethereum

We are very new to Ethereum .We are trying to create a sample application as POC using ethereumJ .

Ethereum ethereum = EthereumFactory.createEthereum();

The above line is getting executed and its running for long time . Its almost 6 hours now .

Is this normal ? Are we missing something ? How we can minimise it ? ( We are ok to use a small test network . )

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Any blockchain-related processing is inherently compute & resource hungry.

To start with, may it would help if we understand your operating environment & specifications.

E.g. hardware (cpu, ram, etc); software (os, runtime, etc); versions (os, runtime, ethereumj, etc);

Answer (score 0):

Model Name:    MacBook Pro
 Model Identifier:    MacBookPro10,2
 Processor Name:    Intel Core i5
 Processor Speed:    2.6 GHz
 Number of Processors:    1
 Total Number of Cores:    2
 L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
 L3 Cache:    3 MB
 Memory:    8 GB